# CentOS 7 kickstart file, add entry to /etc/hosts

Tags: centos, centos7, kickstart

I have a CentOS 7 kickstart file working quite nicely, mostly. The `%packages` section fails because I need to add an entry to /etc/hosts to point mirrorlist.centos.org to our internal company repo. I can add the entry in the `%post` section no worries but that seems to run after packages. I tried added it to the `%pre` section but it never appears in /etc/hosts. From the documentation the pre section is run before install begins so I'm guessing the filesystem doesn't even exist yet. I can move the packages to the `%post` section and just run `yum install <my package>` but was thinking it would be a bit neater using the packages section. Here's my full kick start file:

```
install
cdrom
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
network --bootproto=dhcp --noipv6 --onboot=on --device=eth0
rootpw --plaintext XXXX
firewall --disabled
selinux --permissive
timezone UTC
unsupported_hardware
bootloader --timeout=1 --location=mbr --append="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
text
skipx
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart --nohome --nolvm
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512 --kickstart
firstboot --disabled
reboot --eject
user --name=vagrant --plaintext --password XXXX

%packages --nobase --ignoremissing --excludedocs --instLangs=en_US.utf8
# vagrant needs this to copy initial files via scp
openssh-clients
sudo
selinux-policy-devel
wget
nfs-utils
net-tools
tar
bzip2
deltarpm
rsync
qemu-guest-agent
-fprintd-pam
-intltool

# unnecessary firmware
-*firmware
-microcode_ctl
%end

%pre --log=/mnt/ks-pre.log
#!/bin/sh
echo X.X.X.X   mirrorlist.centos.org >> /etc/hosts
touch /mnt/hello
touch /root/hello
%end

%post --log=/root/ks-post.log
echo X.X.X.X mirrorlist.centos.org >> /etc/hosts
# sudo
echo 'Defaults:vagrant !requiretty' > /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
echo '%vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant

# Enable hyper-v daemons only if using hyper-v virtualization
if [ $(virt-what) == "hyperv" ]; then
    yum -y install hyperv-daemons cifs-utils
    systemctl enable hypervvssd
    systemctl enable hypervkvpd
fi

# Since we disable consistent network naming, we need to make sure the eth0
# configuration file is in place so it will come up.
# Delete other network configuration first because RHEL/C7 networking will not
# restart successfully if there are configuration files for devices that do not
# exist.
rm -f /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-e*
cat > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 << _EOF_
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
_EOF_

#add our SSH key as a login method
mkdir /root/.ssh
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys << _EOF_
ssh-rsa xxxxxx
_EOF_
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

#cloud init
yum install -y cloud-init
cat > /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_dpkg.cfg << _EOF_
datasource_list: [ NoCloud, None ]
_EOF_
systemctl enable cloud-init

cat > /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg << _EOF_
users:
 - default

disable_root: 0
ssh_pwauth:   1

mount_default_fields: [~, ~, 'auto', 'defaults,nofail,x-systemd.requires=cloud-init.service', '0', '2']
resize_rootfs_tmp: /dev
ssh_deletekeys:   0
ssh_genkeytypes:  ~
syslog_fix_perms: ~
disable_vmware_customization: true

cloud_init_modules:
 - disk_setup
 - migrator
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - growpart
 - resizefs
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - update_etc_hosts
 - rsyslog
 - users-groups
 - ssh

cloud_config_modules:
 - mounts
 - locale
 - set-passwords
 - rh_subscription
 - yum-add-repo
 - package-update-upgrade-install
 - timezone
 - puppet
 - chef
 - salt-minion
 - mcollective
 - disable-ec2-metadata
 - runcmd

cloud_final_modules:
 - rightscale_userdata
 - scripts-per-once
 - scripts-per-boot
 - scripts-per-instance
 - scripts-user
 - ssh-authkey-fingerprints
 - keys-to-console
 - phone-home
 - final-message
 - power-state-change

system_info:
  default_user:
    name: centos
    lock_passwd: true
    gecos: Cloud User
    groups: [adm, systemd-journal]
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    shell: /bin/bash
  distro: rhel
  paths:
    cloud_dir: /var/lib/cloud
    templates_dir: /etc/cloud/templates
  ssh_svcname: sshd

# vim:syntax=yaml
_EOF_

echo Complete

%end
```

Comment: The installer doesn’t really use the yum repository definitions yet but rather relies on the installation tree definition in the kickstart file IIRC. You define the location with for example `url --url http://server/path`  and don’t have to deal with overriding the default mirror list. Additional/custom repo’s can be defined with `repo --name=repoid [--baseurl=<url>|--mirrorlist=url] [options]`   https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax

Comment: So what you're saying is the packages section is only really for installing packages from the installation media? And anything else I want to install I should do in `%post`? If so that does make a lot of sense. During the install you wouldn't generally install anything outside the installation media.

Comment: Its been a long time since I manually crafted kickstart files but the installer doesn’t run with the eventual /etc/ yum.repos yet until you enter the %post and chroot to the new system. Until then it only works with what content you provide the installer with in the install tree and/or explicit additional repo lines you set

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer my own question, based on info from @HBruijn. It appears that the packages section is only designed to install packages from the installation media. This makes sense as you would generally not use external repos during the installation phase of the OS. Generally you would install the OS and then install additional packages. So hence it makes sense to use the post section for this. There it's easy to add an entry to `/etc/hosts` and then install additional packages.